# Making a box character in UE4, not a capsule

Tags: c++, unreal-4, blueprints

I want to make a character for a Breakout game that is a kind of cube.

From the instructions from Unreal it appears I need to create a 'Character' blueprint. But when i do this, it comes with CapsuleComponent (Inherited) and I can't change the shape/mesh.

I could perhaps turn off collision on the capsule, but is that really the way it has to be. The capsule is annoying and not needed in this case. I just want a block that I can move left to right with A and D key.

Am I approaching this wrong completely? Do I need a 'Character' blueprint in order to make such a controllable Paddle for Breakout game?

Comment: You'd be better off with a pawn, not a character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++ you can just destroy the `CapsuleCompoennt`, however the `ACharacter` class is intended to use the `CapsuleComponent` many of its underlying functions are relying on a `CapsuleComponent`.

With that said you probably better to use APawn - and add all the bells and whistles manually. - Yes it will lose all the `ACharacter's` bells and whistles.

Leaving the `CapsuleComponent` without collisions is probably an option.

If you are planning to use `UCharacterMovementComponent` of some kind - it will assume a proper capsule - it is possible to fix/override everything, but it is up to you to answer if it is worth the effort.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. Sadlu I cannot upvote you as of yet. I am going to look at APawn soon, although right now I have gone back to basics and just following all the very basic tutorials for adding Actors etc. I'm slowly getting to grips with how to become Unreal ;]  thanks again all those providing help

Comment: Glad to be useful